# The very first clojure compiler?

Tags: clojure

Clojure is written mainly in Clojure, but there had to be a "first" version of a clojure compiler that was written in something else, presumably Java.

Is the code of that compiler available anywhere?

My interest is purely academic, not productional, I'd like to see the way that Rich Hickey handled the chicken/egg problem.

Comment: this is one of the first commits to github... you can move forward from there. https://github.com/clojure/clojure/tree/894a0c81075b8f4b64b7f890ab0c8522a7a9986a

Comment: From the talks I've listened to recently it sounds like there's still a ton of Java code at the core of Clojure.  I haven't grabbed the source yet, but wouldn't be surprised at all if that core is just enough to get the REPL/base operations up and then all the extensions on top of it are in Clojure bootstrapping off of that.  Probably not much benefit to going back and making a completely Clojure compiler as that would bring in historical dependencies in the case of data loss.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch You should grab the source and take a look. A lot of things that you use in Clojure are just java classes. e.g. Keywords, Atoms. If you're familar at all with Java it makes it easy to look at the source and understand what these things do.

Answer (score 10):

The clojure compiler is written in java, not clojure. So the current version is the one that will satisfy your curiosity. Of course it's a reasonable point of view to say that macros are part of the compiler, and those are indeed written in clojure, but they are not relevant to the chicken/egg problem you mention, which is solved by having the compiler in Java.

Comment: there has been a continuous interested in seeing "Clojure in Clojure" forever ... someday perhaps :)

Answer (score 5):

Compiler bootstrapping is a common issue when you write your compiler in the same language as that which you are compiling.

In the case of Clojure, however, the compiler [is written in Java](http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Compiler+in+Clojure), so no tricky games required.

For fun historcal reference, GHC, the Haskell compiler (written in Haskell), was originally compiled via [Lazy ML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_ML).

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this relates to your interests, but Rich had originally worked on a language called DotLisp and for that he began with a study of JScheme, which he used as a basis for the original code and eventually replaced completely.

DotLisp is here: http://dotlisp.sourceforge.net/dotlisp.htm

JScheme is here: http://jscheme.sourceforge.net/jscheme/main.html

(Trivia: one of the authors of JScheme is Brandeis professor Tim Hickey, no known relation to Rich.)